# How should BloC be structured in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, structure, bloc

I'm new to BloC and Flutter. For a single simple screen it should works without problem. But let's take a look at my case, I'm confused on how to use the BloC pattern.

I have a single screen called `Container`, which container a `PageView` of `Content` screen. Say I have 5 pages within that `PageView`. These pages count is dynamic. The pages only differ the data.

I'm thinking about 2 ways of implementing this:

1/ Using **ONE single** bloc and pass it to my 5 child `Content`.

2/ Using **one bloc** for the `Container` and **another bloc** for the `Content`. So this seems to be nested blocs. the `ContainerBloc` will contains the list of `ContentBloc`.

**For the 1st approach**. The problem that I see is the re-rendering problem. I will create a list of data of each page:

```
List<List<String>> allData = [];
BehaviorSubject<List<List<String>>> _allData = BehaviorSubject<List<List<String>>>();

Observable<List<String>> getData(index) => _allData.stream.map((list) => list[index]); //This stream returns the list at the index
```

and each page will listen to the data by:

```
//StreamBuilder in the UI
stream: widget.bloc.getData(index);
```

and the update method for the data should be like:

```
void updateData(int index, List<String> newData) {
    List<String> temp = allData[index];
    temp.add(newData);
    allData[index] = temp;
    _allData.sink.add(allData);
}
```

As I understand, once one page is updated. All other page will re-render because they all listen to the `getData(index)` stream which will be triggered by the`_allData.sink.add(allData);`
So I think all pages will be re-rendered even though the data of that page is not changed.

**For the 2nd approach**. I don't know if it would be best practice to have nested bloc like that. There maybe some case when the `ContainerBloc` must listen to some of the `ContentBloc` output.

I'm kinda confused now.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56163563/bloc-how-to-pass-it/56169581#56169581 this should help you. Structuring BLoC is very comprehensive topic and you won't find definite answer.